# Eigenvectors restricted to a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, maxima-minima

I want to find the unit vector $m$ which minimises the following expression

$m^T Sm$

where $S$ is a real symmetric matrix of shape $n$x$n$. This is not an eigenvalue problem as $m$ is restricted to lie in a subspace of $S$. For example,

$m = \alpha m_1 + \beta m_2$

where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are known but are not one of the four main subspaces of $S$.

I understand that the solution will involve finding the principle axes of an ellipse on the subspace.

Ideally, I want a solution which does not involve interations or finding the eigenvectors of large matrices.

Comment: What does a subspace of a matrix mean?

Comment: Here, the subspace purely means its a space defined by one or more nx1 vectors. I am interested in cases where there are more than one vector defining the space